# Derivation of momentum balance equation from covariant derivative of energy-momentum tensor

Tags: derivatives, tensors

I am trying to derive the ($\beta = 0$, $\alpha = 1$) and ($\beta = 1$, $\alpha = 1$) components of the covarinat derivative of the energy-momentum tensor which is, $\nabla_{\alpha}T_{\beta}^{\alpha}=0$. The equations I'm trying to derive are,

$\beta = 0,\alpha = 1$:
$\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} \Big(  r^2 (\rho + p) v (1-\frac{2M}{r}+v^2)^{1/2} \Big) =0$

$\beta = 1,\alpha = 1$:
$v \frac{dv}{dr}= - \frac{dp}{dr} \Big( \frac{1-\frac{2M}{r}+v^2}{\rho+p} \Big) - \frac{M}{r^2}$

I've started with the line element,

$-ds^2 = - e^{\mu}dt^2 + e^{\lambda}dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2) $.

The energy-momentum tensor is given by,
$T^{\alpha \beta} = (\rho + p)u^{\alpha} u^{\beta} + p g^{\alpha \beta}$, where, $u^{\alpha} = \frac{dx^{\alpha}}{ds}$ and also $u^{\alpha} u_{\alpha}=-1$ with $u^{\alpha}$ being the four velocity and $g_{\alpha \beta}$ is the metric tensor.

I've taken $u^1 = v(r)$ and derived $(u^0)^2 = \frac{1-\frac{2M}{r}+v^2}{(1-\frac{2M}{r})^2}$ and det $g = r^4$. Four-velocity components vanishes for $\alpha > 0$.

The covariant derivative of $T_{\beta}^{\alpha}$ looks like:
$\nabla_{\alpha} T_{\beta}^{\alpha}= \frac{\partial T_{\beta}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} + T^{k}_{\beta} \Gamma_{k\alpha}^{\alpha} - T^{\alpha}_{k} \Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{k}$

I've also used the identity: $\Gamma_{ki}^{i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} (ln(\sqrt{g}))$.

With all this keeping in mind I get for the $\beta = 0, \alpha=1$ :

$\frac{\partial T_{0}^{1}}{\partial x^{1}} +  T_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (ln(\sqrt{g})) -  T_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (ln(\sqrt{g}))  =0$
$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big( (\rho + p) u^1 u_0 \Big) =0$
$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dr} \Big( (\rho + p) v (1-\frac{2M}{r}+v^2)^{1/2} \Big) =0$

I'm not getting the $r^2$ term inside the derivative.

Again for  $\beta = 1, \alpha=1$ :

$\frac{\partial T_{1}^{1}}{\partial x^{1}} +  T_{1}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (ln(\sqrt{g})) -  T_{1}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (ln(\sqrt{g}))  =0$
$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big( (\rho + p) u^1 u_1 + p \delta^1_1 \Big) =0$
$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dr} \Big( \rho \Big) =0$

Please help me find the derivation of these two terms. Thank you.